# PyCharm not respond to my change in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, python, pycharm

I am developing a simple web application integrated with MySQL database. I am using PyCharm to write Python, HTML, JavaScript, CSS. After I make change to my JavaScript and I run my application on Chrome, the Chrome console suggests that the change did not apply. I already invalid PyCharm caches and restart Pycharm, it still cannot work. Anyone has idea about this?

PS: if I rename the JavaScript file, it will work. But what is the reason of this problem? And how can I solve it without renaming?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the file actually change?

Comment: @KlausD. Do you mean the content? Yes, I comment one function and add a new one, but the console log suggests it used the old function.

Comment: check if your browser is caching js files. check if the problem persists if you edit js files in another editor.

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy I disable the cache and it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Open the Chrome Developer tool setting, and disable the cache.

credit to @All is Vanity